# How can i remove pages generated from image attachments on wordpress?

Tags: database, wordpress, phpmyadmin

Image attachment pages show up in search results on website. I need to know how i can remove ones that are currently there. If i can only do this in my database, how can i make sure i delete the actual attachment pages and not the original pages themselves.

[here is where the problem is](http://artistslibrary.org/?s=)

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the media attachment page on Yoast SEO if you have installed it. Or you can paste this to your functions.php

```
function myprefix_redirect_attachment_page() {
if ( is_attachment() ) {
    global $post;
    if ( $post && $post->post_parent ) {
        wp_redirect( esc_url( get_permalink( $post->post_parent ) ), 301 );
        exit;
    } else {
        wp_redirect( esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ), 301 );
        exit;
    }
  }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'myprefix_redirect_attachment_page' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this small snippet - add it to the functions.php of your child theme :

```
function remove_attachments_from_search() {
    global $wp_post_types;
    $wp_post_types['attachment']->exclude_from_search = true;
}
add_action('init', 'remove_attachments_from_search');
```

This will exclude attachment post type from search results.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for the snippet. Unfortunately it still does not work. Somehow image attachments still show up in search results.